# Magento 2.2.5 shell script PHP Memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes)

Tags: magento2, php, script, command-line, command

I have a magento 2 script which runs through shell so to not have a timeout issue. It uses php multi curl request and it was running fine. But recently asked our hosting server to increase the PHP cli memory limit from 2048M to 16384M and php-fpm memory_limit was increased that too. And after that I tried running any magento command and we're getting the following error.

PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on line 710. How is this possible it was running fine before and the memory was increased and now this error is showing.

CentOS 7.3
Apache2 httpd-2.4.6-67.el7.centos.5.x86_64
Magento 2.2.5
PHP 7.1.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find php path and version add **memory_limit=-1** before bin/magento. This might solve your issue

like command below :

`/opt/php70/bin/php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile`